# Having Error in Android Manifest while building

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\kcs\AndroidStudioProjects\OURVEDIC\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource xml/backup_descriptor (aka com.binni.ourvedic:xml/backup_descriptor) not found.

This is the error I am having

my code :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.binni.ourvedic">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.OURVEDIC"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So you do have a file `values/xml/backup_descriptor.xml`?

Comment: no I have cloned this file from Github

Answer (score 4):

Remove the line `android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"` in your application tag in `manifest` file, or add the needed `xml` file to your project.

```
<application
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: I removed this line :   android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"  and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

looks like if you have clone the project that uses shared preferences, this error wont go away by simply deleting

```
 android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor
```

In order to solve this problem, create a  new resource directory of type xml in res folder.
Inside this folder create a a file named : "backup_descriptor"
and copy this tag into it :

```
<full-backup-content>
</full-backup-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio , try This

```
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Only remove

```
<meta-data
 android:name="preloaded_fonts"
 android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
```